# Java midi inconsistent playback quality

Tags: java, midi, javasound

I've recently run into a strange bug with playing midis in a game I'm developing. I thought my midi code was working fine since it used to play midis without sounding weird. Now whenever it plays midis, they sound all tinny, echo-y, and loud.

I haven't touched my midi player code for a very long time, so I'm wondering if it's possible that a recent Java update has exposed a bug that has been in my code all along. Or perhaps there's some sort of midi bug in my version of Java that I'm not aware of?

The midis sound fine whenever I play them outside of my game.

I'm running Java 6, update 31, build 1.6.0_31-b05. Here's a SSCCE that reproduces the problem (it reproduces it on my JVM at least):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.midi.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class MidiSSCCE extends JFrame
{

    public MidiSSCCE()
    {
        super("Sound problem SSCCE");
        this.setSize(200,100);

        // instantiate main window panel

        JPanel screenP = new SSCCEPanel(this);
        this.add(screenP);

        // finishing touches on Game window

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println("Game Window successfully created!!!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MidiSSCCE gui = new MidiSSCCE();        
    }
}


/**
*   SSCCEPanel is the JPanel that manages the example's timer, painting, and logic. 
**/

class SSCCEPanel extends JPanel
{
    public Frame parentFrame;
    private Timer timer;
    public int logicLoops;
    public double prevFPS;
    boolean timerReady;

    // The MidiPlayer object is used by the example to play the midi.

    public MidiPlayer midiPlayer;

    public SSCCEPanel(Frame parent)
    {
        super(true);
        parentFrame = parent;
        this.setFocusable(true);

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        logicLoops = 0;

        midiPlayer = new MidiPlayer();

        TimerListener timerListener = new TimerListener();
        prevFPS = 0;
        timerReady = true;
        timer = new Timer(0,timerListener);
        this.setFPS(60);
        timer.start();
    }

    /** 
    *   setFPS()
    *   Preconditions: fps is a quantity of frames per second
    *   Postconditions: Sets the timer's refresh rate so that it 
    *       fires fps times per second.
    **/

    public void setFPS(int fps)
    {
        int mspf = (int) (1000.0 /fps + 0.5);
        timer.setDelay(mspf);
    }


    /**
    *   This is the JPanel's timer listener. It runs the example's logic and repaint
    *   methods each time it gets a timer signal.
    **/

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener
    {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long lastTime = this.startTime;
        int ticks = 0;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Object source = e.getSource();
            if(source == timer)
            {
                // perform a loop through the game's logic and repaint.

                synchronized(this)
                {
                    if(timerReady)
                    {
                        timerReady = false;
                        runSSCCELogic();
                        repaint();
                        timerReady = true;
                    }
                }

                // Logic for Frames per Second counter

                this.ticks++;

                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                if(currentTime - startTime >= 500) 
                {
                    prevFPS =  1000.0 * ticks/(1.0*currentTime - startTime);
                    System.out.println(prevFPS);
                    startTime = currentTime;
                    ticks = 0;
                }

                lastTime = currentTime;
            }
        }
    }


    /**
    *   repaints the SSCCE.
    *   This just shows the current FPS.
    **/

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
            double roundedFPS = Math.round(prevFPS*10)/10.0;

            g2D.setColor(new Color(0x000000));
            g2D.drawString("FPS: " + roundedFPS, 20,20);
            g.dispose();
    }

    /**
    *   runSSCCEELogic()
    *   This is where the run-time logic for the SSCCE example is. 
    *   All it does is load and play a midi called "mymidi.mid" which is located in the same directory.
    **/

    public void runSSCCELogic()
    {
        if(logicLoops == 1)
        {
            midiPlayer.load("http://www.vgmusic.com/music/computer/microsoft/windows/touhou_6_stage3_boss.mid");
            midiPlayer.play(true);
        }

        logicLoops++;
    }
}



/**
*   MidiPlayer
*   A class that allows midi files to be loaded and played. 
**/

class MidiPlayer
{
    private Sequence seq;
    private Sequencer seqr;
    private Synthesizer synth;
    private Receiver receiver;
    private File midiFile;
    private String midiID;
    private boolean loaded;
    private boolean usingHardwareSoundbank;

    // CONSTRUCTORS

    public MidiPlayer()
    {
        loaded = false;
        try
        {
            seqr = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("MIDI error: It appears your system doesn't have a MIDI device or your device is not working.");
        }
    }

    /**
    *   MidiPlayer(String fileName)
    *   Constructor that also loads an initial midi file.
    *   Preconditions: fileName is the name of the midi file to be loaded. 
    *   Postconditions: The MidiPlayer is created and loaded with the midi specified by fileName.
    **/

    public MidiPlayer(String fileName)
    {
        this();
        load(fileName);
    }


    // DATA METHODS

    /**
    *   load(String fileName)
    *   loads a midi file into this MidiPlayer.
    *   Preconditions: fileName is the name of the midi file to be loaded.
    *   Postconditions: fileName is loaded and is ready to be played.
    **/

    public void load(String fileName)
    {
        this.unload();
        try
        {
            URL midiURL =  new URL(fileName);
        //  midiFile = new File(fileName);
            seq = MidiSystem.getSequence(midiURL);

            seqr.open();
            synth.open();

            System.out.println("MidiDeviceInfo: ");
            for(MidiDevice.Info info : MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo())
            {
                System.out.println("\t" + info);
            }
            System.out.println();

            if(synth.getDefaultSoundbank() == null)
            {
                receiver = MidiSystem.getReceiver();
                usingHardwareSoundbank = true;
                System.out.println("using hardware soundbank");
            }
            else
            {
                receiver = synth.getReceiver();
                usingHardwareSoundbank = false;
                System.out.println("using default software soundbank:" + synth.getDefaultSoundbank());
            }
            seqr.getTransmitter().setReceiver(receiver);

            seqr.setSequence(seq);
            loaded = true;
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("MIDI error: Problem occured while reading " + midiFile.getName() + ".");
        }
        catch(InvalidMidiDataException imde)
        {
            System.out.println("MIDI error: " + midiFile.getName() + " is not a valid MIDI file or is unreadable.");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("MIDI error: Unexplained error occured while loading midi.");
        }
    }

    /**
    *   unload()
    *   Unloads the current midi from the MidiPlayer and releases its resources from memory.
    **/

    public void unload()
    {
        this.stop();
        seqr.close();
        midiFile = null;
        loaded = false;
    }

    // OTHER METHODS

    /**
    *   setMidiID(String id)
    *   associates a String ID with the current midi.
    *   Preconditions: id is the ID we are associating with the current midi.
    **/

    public void setMidiID(String id)
    {
        midiID = id;
    }

    /**
    *   getMidiID(String id)
    *
    **/

    public String getMidiID()
    {
        return new String(midiID);
    }

    /**
    *   play(boolean reset)
    *   plays the currently loaded midi.
    *   Preconditions: reset tells our midi whether or nor to begin playing from the start of the midi file's current loop start point.
    *   Postconditions: If reset is true, then the loaded midi begins playing from its loop start point (default 0). 
    *       If reset is false, then the loaded midi resumes playing from its current position.
    **/

    public void play(boolean reset)
    {
        if(reset)
            seqr.setTickPosition(seqr.getLoopStartPoint());
        seqr.start();
    }

    /**
    *   stop()
    *   Pauses the current midi if it was playing.
    **/

    public void stop()
    {
        if(seqr.isOpen())
            seqr.stop();
    }

    /**
    *   isRunning()
    *   Returns true if the current midi is playing. Returns false otherwise.
    **/

    public boolean isRunning()
    {
        return seqr.isRunning();
    }


    /**
    *   loop(int times)
    *   Sets the current midi to loop from start to finish a specific number of times.
    *   Preconditions: times is the number of times we want our midi to loop.
    *   Postconditions: The current midi is set to loop times times. 
    *       If times = -1, the current midi will be set to loop infinitely.
    **/

    public void loop(int times)
    {
        loop(times,0,-1);
    }

    /**
    *   loop(int times)
    *   Sets the current midi to loop from a specified start point to a specified end point a specific number of times.
    *   Preconditions: times is the number of times we want our midi to loop.
    *       start is our loop's start point in ticks.
    *       end is our loop's end point in ticks.
    *   Postconditions: The current midi is set to loop from tick start to tick end times times. 
    *       If times = -1, the current midi will be set to loop infinitely.
    **/

    public void loop(int times, long start, long end)
    {
        if(start < 0)
            start = 0;
        if(end > seqr.getSequence().getTickLength() || end <= 0)
            end = seqr.getSequence().getTickLength();

        if(start >= end && end != -1)
            start = end-1;

        seqr.setLoopStartPoint(start);
        seqr.setLoopEndPoint(end);

        if(times == -1)
            seqr.setLoopCount(Sequencer.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        else
            seqr.setLoopCount(times);

    }


    public void setVolume(double vol)
    {
        try 
        {
            if(usingHardwareSoundbank)
            {
                ShortMessage volumeMessage = new ShortMessage();
                for ( int i = 0; i < 16; i++ ) 
                {
                    volumeMessage.setMessage( ShortMessage.CONTROL_CHANGE, i, 7, (int)(vol*127) );
                    receiver.send( volumeMessage, -1 );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MidiChannel[] channels = synth.getChannels();
                for( int c = 0; channels != null && c < channels.length; c++ )
                {
                  channels[c].controlChange( 7, (int)( vol*127) );
                }
            }
        } 
        catch ( Exception e ) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) I haven't had answers that have solved my problem for most of my questions.
2) Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a change to my MidiPlayer code that seems to have resolved the problem for me. I moved the code where it loads the soundbank and the transmitter's receiver to the constructor instead of in the method where it loads a midi. It no longer sounds really loud and tinny.

```
  package gameEngine;

  import javax.sound.midi.*;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.net.URL;

  /**
  * MidiPlayer
  * author: Stephen Lindberg
  * Last modified: Oct 14, 2011
  * 
  * A class that allows midi files to be loaded and played.
  **/

  public class MidiPlayer
  {
     private Sequence seq;
     private Sequencer seqr;
     private Synthesizer synth;
     private Receiver receiver;
     private File midiFile;
     private String midiID;
     private boolean loaded;
     private boolean usingHardwareSoundbank;
     private float defaultTempo;

     // CONSTRUCTORS

     public MidiPlayer()
     {
        loaded = false;
        try
        {
           seqr = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
           synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();

           // print the user's midi device info
           System.out.println("Setting up Midi Player...");
           System.out.println("MidiDeviceInfo: ");
           for(MidiDevice.Info info : MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo())
           {
              System.out.println("\t" + info.getName() + ": " +info.getDescription());
           }
           System.out.println();

           // obtain the receiver. This will be used for changing volume.

           Soundbank soundbank = synth.getDefaultSoundbank();
           if(soundbank == null)
           {
              receiver = MidiSystem.getReceiver();
              usingHardwareSoundbank = true;
              System.out.println("using hardware soundbank");
           }
           else
           {
              synth.loadAllInstruments(soundbank);
              receiver = synth.getReceiver();
              usingHardwareSoundbank = false;
              System.out.println("using default software soundbank:" + soundbank);
           }
           seqr.getTransmitter().setReceiver(receiver);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
           System.out.println("MIDI error: It appears your system doesn't have a MIDI device or your device is not working.");
        }
     }

     /**
     *  MidiPlayer(String fileName)
     *  Constructor that also loads an initial midi file.
     *  Preconditions: fileName is the name of the midi file to be loaded. 
     *  Postconditions: The MidiPlayer is created and loaded with the midi specified by fileName.
     **/

     public MidiPlayer(String fileName)
     {
        this();
        load(fileName);
     }


     // DATA METHODS

     /**
     *  load(String fileName)
     *  loads a midi file into this MidiPlayer.
     *  Preconditions: fileName is the name of the midi file to be loaded.
     *  Postconditions: fileName is loaded and is ready to be played.
     **/

     public void load(String fileName)
     {
        this.unload();
        try
        {
           URL midiURL =  getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
           seq = MidiSystem.getSequence(midiURL);

           seqr.open();
           synth.open();

           // load our sequence into the sequencer.

           seqr.setSequence(seq);
           loaded = true;
           defaultTempo = seqr.getTempoInBPM();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
           System.out.println("MIDI error: Problem occured while reading " + midiFile.getName() + ".");
        }
        catch(InvalidMidiDataException imde)
        {
           System.out.println("MIDI error: " + midiFile.getName() + " is not a valid MIDI file or is unreadable.");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
           System.out.println("MIDI error: Unexplained error occured while loading midi.");
        }
     }

     /**
     *  unload()
     *  Unloads the current midi from the MidiPlayer and releases its resources from memory.
     **/

     public void unload()
     {
        this.stop();
        seqr.close();
        synth.close();
        midiFile = null;
        loaded = false;
     }

     // OTHER METHODS

     /**
     *  setMidiID(String id)
     *  associates a String ID with the current midi.
     *  Preconditions: id is the ID we are associating with the current midi.
     **/

     public void setMidiID(String id)
     {
        midiID = id;
     }

     /**
     *  getMidiID(String id)
     *
     **/

     public String getMidiID()
     {
        return new String(midiID);
     }

     /**
     *  play(boolean reset)
     *  plays the currently loaded midi.
     *  Preconditions: reset tells our midi whether or nor to begin playing from the start of the midi file's current loop start point.
     *  Postconditions: If reset is true, then the loaded midi begins playing from its loop start point (default 0). 
     *      If reset is false, then the loaded midi resumes playing from its current position.
     **/

     public void play(boolean reset)
     {
        if(reset)
           seqr.setTickPosition(seqr.getLoopStartPoint());
        seqr.start();
     }

     /**
     *  stop()
     *  Pauses the current midi if it was playing.
     **/

     public void stop()
     {
        if(seqr.isOpen())
           seqr.stop();
     }

     /**
     *  isRunning()
     *  Returns true if the current midi is playing. Returns false otherwise.
     **/

     public boolean isRunning()
     {
        return seqr.isRunning();
     }



     /**
     *  getTempo()
     *  Returns the current tempo of the MidiPlayer in BPM (Beats per Minute).
     **/

     public float getTempo()
     {
        return seqr.getTempoInBPM();
     }

     /**
     *  loop(int times)
     *  Sets the current midi to loop from start to finish a specific number of times.
     *  Preconditions: times is the number of times we want our midi to loop.
     *  Postconditions: The current midi is set to loop times times. 
     *      If times = -1, the current midi will be set to loop infinitely.
     **/

     public void loop(int times)
     {
        loop(times,0,-1);
     }

     /**
     *  loop(int times)
     *  Sets the current midi to loop from a specified start point to a specified end point a specific number of times.
     *  Preconditions: times is the number of times we want our midi to loop.
     *      start is our loop's start point in ticks.
     *      end is our loop's end point in ticks.
     *  Postconditions: The current midi is set to loop from tick start to tick end times times. 
     *      If times = -1, the current midi will be set to loop infinitely.
     **/

     public void loop(int times, long start, long end)
     {
        if(start < 0)
           start = 0;
        if(end > seqr.getSequence().getTickLength() || end <= 0)
           end = seqr.getSequence().getTickLength();

        if(start >= end && end != -1)
           start = end-1;

        seqr.setLoopStartPoint(start);
        seqr.setLoopEndPoint(end);

        if(times == -1)
           seqr.setLoopCount(Sequencer.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        else
           seqr.setLoopCount(times);

     }

     /**
     *  resetTempo()
     *  Resets the MidiPlayer's tempo the the initial tempo of its current midi.
     **/

     public void resetTempo()
     {
        this.changeTempo(this.defaultTempo);
     }

     /**
     *  changeTempo(float bpm)
     *  Changes the MidiPlayer's current tempo.
     *  Preconditions: bpm is the MidiPlayer's new tempo in BPM (Beats per Minute).
     *  Postconditions: The MidiPlayer's current tempo is set to bpm BPM.
     **/

     public void changeTempo(float bpm)
     {
        double lengthCoeff = bpm/seqr.getTempoInBPM();

        seqr.setLoopStartPoint((long) (seqr.getLoopStartPoint()*lengthCoeff));
        seqr.setLoopEndPoint((long) (seqr.getLoopEndPoint()*lengthCoeff));

        seqr.setTempoInBPM(bpm);
     }


     public void setVolume(double vol)
     {
        System.out.println("Midi volume change request: " + vol);

        try 
        {
           if(usingHardwareSoundbank)
           {
              ShortMessage volumeMessage = new ShortMessage();
              for ( int i = 0; i < 16; i++ ) 
              {
                 volumeMessage.setMessage( ShortMessage.CONTROL_CHANGE, i, 7, (int)(vol*127) );
                 receiver.send( volumeMessage, -1 );
              }
           }
           else
           {
              MidiChannel[] channels = synth.getChannels();

              for( int c = 0; c < channels.length; c++ )
              {
                 if(channels[c] != null) {
                    channels[c].controlChange( 7, (int)( vol*127) );
                 }
              }
           }
        } 
        catch ( Exception e ) 
        {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

  }
```

Comment: I've also been having problems with getting midi volume control to work, but that's not the subject of this question, so I'll start a new question for that issue I guess...

Answer (score 2):

The sound quality of MIDI is dependent on the synth generating the sound.  It shouldn't have anything to do with your code.

Most likely, it is an issue with your sound card, but that isn't always what generates the sound, especially these days.  Under Windows, there is a software synth from Microsoft that does all that.  In any case, this won't have anything to do with your code.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the conclusion I'm arriving at. I've had some friends test out my SSCCE with mixed results. For some, the midi sounds fine, but some are having my same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem is with my JRE build. I tried running this simple example for playing midis that Andrew linked me to:

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;
import java.net.URL;

class PlayMidi {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          URL url = new URL("http://www.vgmusic.com/music/computer/microsoft/windows/touhou_6_stage3_boss.mid");

          Sequence sequence = MidiSystem.getSequence(url);
          Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();

          sequencer.open();
          sequencer.setSequence(sequence);

          sequencer.start();
     }
}
```

and the midi's sound quality still didn't improve. I ran both my SSCCE and the above minimal example using Java 6_31 and Java 6_32.

In conclusion, this is a problem inherent in Java 6_31 and Java 6_32. So, I guess I'm out of luck until Sun/Oracle releases the next JRE build which will hopefully has this problem resolved.

EDIT:

I just had a friend who has Java 6_31 installed test this out on his machine. He didn't notice any difference in sound quality when he ran my java example vs playing the midi outside of Java. So, it is could also be likely that the problem has something to do with my machine specifically instead of it being a bug in Java. However, another friend just tested it and was also experiencing the same problem I'm having.

In conclusion, the problem is either inherent in Java versions past 6_31, in the sound devices of some machines, or a combination of both. The problem is probably not worth pursuing any further in native java.

Comment: nevermind. I found a fix for my code that resolves the issue on my machine. (Haven't tested it yet with anyone else) See my accepted answer.